# List to Set conversion is not working properly in APEX

Tags: apex, list, set

I assume that this is a pretty basic question but I am wondering why I can't be able to convert a List of String to a Set of String. I have tried the below snippet but didn't get the unique string value set as expected.

```
List<String> lstObjectTypeName = new List<String>();        
String str1 = 'Program, Project, Project Task';
String str2 = 'Project, Project Task';
String str3 = 'Project Task';

lstObjectTypeName.addAll(str1.split(','));
lstObjectTypeName.addAll(str2.split(','));
lstObjectTypeName.addAll(str3.split(','));

Set<String> setObjectTypeName = new Set<String>();
for(String objName : lstObjectTypeName) {
    System.debug(!setObjectTypeName.contains(objName) + '::::' + objName + '::::' + lstObjectTypeName + '::::' + setObjectTypeName);
    if(!setObjectTypeName.contains(objName)) {
        setObjectTypeName.add(objName);
    }  
}
System.debug('Object Type Name' + lstObjectTypeName);
System.debug('Object Type Name Set :::: ' + setObjectTypeName);
```

I am expecting the set as,

Object Type Name Set :::: {Program, Project, Project Task}

But I am getting the response as like below,

Object Type Name          (Program,  Project,  Project Task, Project,  Project Task, Project Task)
Object Type Name Set :::: { Project,  Project Task, Program, Project, Project Task}

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you split it with `,` it will include spaces too, so it will change the hash value of the string. So `set` will not exclude it. As `Project Task` and  `Project Task` is not same, as the later includes a space.

That is why you see `{ Project, Project Task, Program, Project, Project Task}`.

try with removing all the spaces.

```
List<String> lstObjectTypeName = new List<String>();
String str1 = 'Program,Project,Project Task';
String str2 = 'Project,Project Task';
String str3 = 'Project Task';

lstObjectTypeName.addAll(str1.split(','));
lstObjectTypeName.addAll(str2.split(','));
lstObjectTypeName.addAll(str3.split(','));

Set<String> setObjectTypeName = new Set<String>();
setObjectTypeName.addAll(lstObjectTypeName);
System.debug('Object Type Name' + lstObjectTypeName);
System.debug('Object Type Name Set :::: ' + setObjectTypeName);
```

and you will get desired result.

Also no need to iterate `List` and add, `set` already has a method to include list directly, as shown above.

Comment: Oh Thanks @nagendra singh. Actually I have used the addAll method to create the set, but got the exact same response, so tried to loop it. Anyway will try this.